# need help on posting on user wall

Tags: php, facebook

need help below is the code of index.php of my application and i want to Post on user wall after the user authorize my application with OFFLINE_ACCESS AND publish_stram

```
<?php 

 $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXX";

 $app_secret = "XXXXXXX";

 $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/esccounsel/";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . ("&scope=read_stream publish_stream offline_access");

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
        echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
 } 

?>
```

I want to post directly on user wall please answer

Comment: I've just edited your code, **NEVER EVER** share your application secret!! I suggest you generate a new one **NOW**

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the [Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)
2. No need for the `offline_access` permission
3. Get familiar with the PHP-SDK and use the code in the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) page as your index, something like:

   ```
   <?php
   require '../src/facebook.php';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
     'secret' => 'XXXXXXXX',
     'cookie' => true,
   ));

   $session = $facebook->getSession();
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
       "req_perms" => "publish_stream"
   ));
   $me = null;

   if ($session) {
     try {
       $uid = $facebook->getUser();
       $me = $facebook->api('/me');

       echo "Welcome User: " . $me['name'] . "<br />";

       $post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", array("message"=>"Hello World!"));
       if(isset($post_id))
           echo "A new post to your wall has been posted with id: $post_id";

     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       error_log($e);
     }
   } else {
       echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: @ifaour is it possible possible to post direectly to the user wall on next day

Comment: @Danish: yes but this time you need to save the User ID in your DB and then use it:`$facebook->api("/$id_from_db/feed", "post", array("message"=>"Hello World!"));`

Comment: @ifaour sorry to disturb you again i got the following error 
when page loaded its blank
and url  is http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=166172283431392&connect=1&type=connect

Comment: @ifaour sorry to disturb you again i got the following error when page loaded its blank and url is http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=166172283431392&connect=1&type=connect

Comment: @Danish: Have the initial code I posted worked for you? let us take it step by step..

Comment: @ifaour first i use the above code in index but its got the same error than i second i create new file which caring your above code and use redirecturl to redirect to welcome file which caring your code but also got the same error as above i dont known why??