# Link to prefill status on facebook

Tags: facebook

Twitter offers a dead simple method for prepoulating someones status for posting. Specifically, its as easy as http://twitter.com/?status=message .

I am looking for a similar method to use for facebook. Unfortunately, all I can find are like buttons and similar, which don't fit my need (the content we want posted does not have its own page). Is there any method on facebook to easily set someones status?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Facebook, to post to a certain user's profile you need the following:

1. The user to authenticate/authorize your application
2. You ask for an extended permission to be able to post to his wall (`publish_stream` in this case)
3. Capture the user id and use it to post whatever you want

Now doing the is easy and can be done in different ways, let's take the PHP-SDK [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) page and modify it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '191149314281714',
  'secret' => '73b67bf1c825fa47efae70a46c18906b',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream'
  );
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I changed the following from the original example:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  "scope" => "publish_stream"
));
```

Now that the user granted your application the right permission you can post to his wall, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126665/need-help-on-posting-on-user-wall/5127747#5127747) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a simple way to share content onto Facebook.  Facebook is deprecating the Share Button, but still seems to support direct URL calls to the Share page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=cnn.com&t=great+news+site
```

So, create a link that opens your URL in a new window, like in this Javascript:

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(myUrl)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(myTitle),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

You mention prefilling it with default text.  I believe Facebook explicitly forbids this now.  They say this in the [Feed Dialog page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), which should pretty much cover their policy for the Sharer page too:

> This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work at https://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=woot

But nolonger does.