# Relevant Dynamic Facebook Landingpage?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to present relevant/dynamic data/information to facebook-users who visits a facebook landingpage?

Example:

Person A (already logged in to facebook) visits http://apps.facebook.com/appname/ and sees relevant information, like "welcome Person A, X number of your friends are here..."

Thank you!

Comment: Yup every thing possible. You just need to grab the information of the user who is conecting with your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook will **not** give you the User ID (Person A) until the user authorizes your application. From there you can get the user's friends that authorized the application (X number of your friends are here..)

A small example using the [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126665/need-help-on-posting-on-user-wall/5127747#5127747).

Comment: Always present precise answer

Answer (score 0):

What if it's an internal application? Can we get something from the URL? I heard something about getting the user location and age before they connect to the application.

Comment: In order to create a personalized user experience, Facebook sends your app information about the user. This information is passed to your Canvas URL using HTTP POST within a single signed_request parameter which contains a base64url encoded JSON object.