# Authenticating a FACEBOOK Application - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i need to authenticate before posting to my own wall, so here is my code

```
function get_app_token($appid, $appsecret)
{
$args = array(
'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
'client_id' => $appid,
'client_secret' => $appsecret
);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

return json_encode($data);
}

$token = get_app_token($appid, $appsecret);
$attachment = array('message' => '',
        'access_token' => $token,
                'name' => 'Attachment Name',
                'caption' => 'Attachment Caption',
                'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/',
                'description' => 'Description .....',
                'picture' => 'http://www.google.com/logo.jpg',
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Action Text', 
                                  'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/'))
                );

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

i got error **OAuthException
,Invalid OAuth access token signature.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [need help on posting on user wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126665/need-help-on-posting-on-user-wall)

Comment: The link I posted above will get you started. You are requesting an "Application Access Token"! this is not used to do tasks on the user's behalf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get access_token from session array of facebook object directly.

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$session['access_token'];
```

of course you need to be authorized. if session is not set you must redirect to loginUrl

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream'));
// this will return url for your authorization
```

and request permission you need.

Answer (score 0):

Value of `$token` is `access_token=<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

You cannot pass `$token` value directly to the `access_token` parameter.

```
$token = get_app_token($appid, $appsecret);
$access_token = split('=',$token);
$attachment = array(
                    'message' => '',
                    'access_token' => $access_token[1],
                    'name' => 'Attachment Name',
                    'caption' => 'Attachment Caption',
                    'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/',
                    'description' => 'Description .....',
                    'picture' => 'http://www.google.com/logo.jpg',
                    'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Action Text', 
                              'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/'))
              );
```

Hope this will helps in making that work... :)

Comment: i appreciate your help but it returned the same error, plz have a look at my code http://www.web-shine.in/tutorials/fb/code.txt

Answer (score -1):

A `client_credentials` access token doesn't give any access to `/me` (who would "me" be in this case? there's nothing that ties it to a user), let alone posting access. It is for use only with application-level Graph API calls, like to get an application's Insights data.

Comment: can you help me fix the prob ?

Comment: You need to rewrite your oauth flow entirely.

Comment: i am very new to FB app, i started just today, so i need code :|

Comment: The documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) should be reasonably easy to follow. This isn't really a site for free code - I get paid to write code, usually.

Comment: can you write a little code which just post a blah blah message to the wall ?