# Facebook App Auto-Banned

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a simple Facebook app that tells the user how well they use their Facebook profile. And I've had it running on Facebook and twice now it has been auto-banned by Facebook's system. The first time it was probably due to us having a lot of people in the office here add the app and send requests to their friends, and possibly because we were auto-populating the message parameter in wall posts. Well I changed all that and tried to re-launch the app. And we were auto-banned a second time. I'm not sure at all why, and I'm getting no feedback from Facebook on the issue. Here's a quick overview of the interactions we have with the graph api.

- Check Session (php sdk)
- If no session get the login link (php sdk)
- Init Javascript sdk
- FB.canvas.setSize (javascript SDK)
- Request these permissions

  email,user_location,read_stream,manage_pages,user_checkins,user_likes,user_events,user_notes,publish_stream
- Get uid (php sdk)
- Get /me from api (php sdk)
- Get /me/friends from api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/feed from api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/accounts from api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/checkins from api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/likes from api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/eventsfrom api (php sdk)
- Get /$uid/notesfrom api (php sdk)
- Post FB.ui app requests (javascript sdk), user clicks a button to bring up dialog
- Post FB.ui feed (javascript sdk), user clicks button, no message prefilled
- Post FB.ui app requests (javascript sdk), user clicks a button to bring up dialog
- Post FB.ui app requests (javascript sdk), user clicks a button to bring up dialog

Those are all the interactions, if you guys have any idea if any of this could be causing my app to get auto-banned please let me know. I'm at a loss and I don't want to try and launch it again only to get it banned once more.

If you require any additional information let me know. And thanks for your time.

Comment: can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581593/authenticating-a-facebook-application-php/5582235#5582235

Comment: @Sourav: This isn't Yahoo Answers. Don't post links to your question wherever you can and ask people to help you. If you have an actual question that people can answer, open a new question. The answers will pour in.

Answer (score 1):

I too banned 15 times... :D

These could the reason for banned:

1. You are not allow to have more than 4 permissions. if still necessary, give full control over all permissions to users.
2. For every action which uses your permissions should be well cleared to users. (Put checkboxes if needed)
3. If you are using javascript sdk for wall post, then what the need of publish_stream permission? -> This is taken into consideration as spamming.
4. Provide your privacy policy to users (Add privacy url in facebook setting)

Overall i suggest you to reduce permissions.

"LESS PERMISSIONS MORE USERS"

[For more and detailed information](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/). Hope this gives you some idea... :)

Comment: Thanks for your insight, where did you get the 4 permissions figure from? I've seen many apps require more permissions. Good point about the publish_stream permission though I'll give that a try. Thanks again.

Comment: those who have more than 4 permissions they all clearly mentioned and gave full access to user to control it... :) Thank... Accepted Answer?? :)

Comment: I would love to make yours the accepted answer, however I don't understand what you mean by "they all clearly mentioned and gave full access to user to control it"

Comment: means there is nothing hidden from users, when they actually allow application to use those permissions... means no misuses... :)

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't help me.