# faceBook Application Issue

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I am Using following to get appToken

```
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$config->getAppId().'&client_secret='.$config->getAppSecret().'&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=offline_access');  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
$app_token= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**and uses graph api to get details from request id using following snippet**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$requestId.'?'.$app_token);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$request= curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

**Everything works fine except in IE...**

when using my app in IE i got following error in log

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
 thrown in **facebook.php on line 560,**
referer: http://< my_url >?request_ids=1934696176864&ref=notif&notif_t=app_request

**EDIT** - Complete Code

```
<?php 
    include './facebook.php';
    include './config.php';
    include './database.php';

    $config = new Config();
    $database = new Database();
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $config->getAppId(),
        'secret' => $config->getAppSecret(),
        'cookie' => false,
    ));

$sent_to_id='';
if(isset($_GET['request_ids']) && !empty($_GET['request_ids'])){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$config->getAppId().'&client_secret='.$config->getAppSecret().'&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=offline_access');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $app_token= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'Acces_Token:    '.$app_token .", Session Acces Token: ".$session['access_token'];

    //$app_token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$config->getAppId().'&client_secret='.$config->getAppSecret().'&grant_type=client_credentials'); //Get application token
    $sent   = explode(',', $_GET['request_ids']);  //Convert csv to array
    $count = count($sent); //count how many objects in array
    for ($a = 0; $a < $count; $a++) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$sent[$a].'?'.$app_token);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $request= curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        //$request = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$sent[$a].'?'.$app_token);
        preg_match("/\"to\":\{\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"id\":\"(.*?)\"/i", $request, $getInfo);
        echo "sent[.".$a."] : ". $sent[$a] .", getInfo[1]: " . $getInfo[1] . ", getInfo[2]: ". $getInfo[2] ;
        echo ", AppToken: ".$app_token;
        $sent_to_name_temp= $getInfo[1];
        $sent_to_id_temp =  $getInfo[2];

        if(!empty($sent_to_name_temp) && !empty($sent_to_id_temp)){
                $sent_to_id .=  $getInfo[2] . ',';  
        }
    }
}
$sent_to_id = substr($sent_to_id, 0 , strlen($sent_to_id));
$userIds = explode(',', $sent_to_id);

$database->insert_invites($_GET['id'],$_GET['request_ids'], $userIds);
?>
```

Client Side code

```
        function showInvite(invitedby)  {
            FB.ui({ 
                method: "apprequests", 
                message: "Hey this is just for a testing App!",
                data: "accepted", //This will be passed back to you when a user accepts the request
                title: "Title wil be here!"
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response && response.request_ids) {
                    ajaxRequest(invitedby, response.request_ids);
                    $(".message").html("Your invitation has been sent");
                } else {
                    //alert('You must select some friends to send invitation!');
                }
            });
        }
        function ajaxRequest(invitedby, requestIds){
            $.ajax({
                url:"insertInvites.php?id=" + invitedby +"&request_ids="+requestIds,
                success:function(){
                    //alert("Successfully inserted into table");
                },
                failure:function(){
                    //alert("Error while insertting into database");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? try adding how you are setting the `$requestId` variable. Also are you making other FB calls?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is running on the server, not in the browser. You need to check the input you're getting from the one particular browser (IE) and figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I rollback your change by mistake, was not able to figure out what you have changed. Sorry

Comment: Um, your entire post is mis-formatted. I've cleaned it up again by re-applying the correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$session['access_token'];
```

have a look @ [Authenticating a FACEBOOK Application - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581593/authenticating-a-facebook-application-php)

Comment: access_token is blank for $session['access_token'];

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with IE9 and my canvas app because IE9 by default rejects 3rd party cookies without a proper compact privacy policy.

This fixed my IE specific problem.)

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');