# Update facebook status using php

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I know it's a very old question.But i really bound to ask the same question again.How can i update my status using PHP?Because i find several solutions in google and stackoverflow but non of that currently works.May be the cause of facebook up gradation process or anything else.
I chk: 
1) http://360percents.com/posts/php-curl-status-update-working-example-sep-2010/
2) http://www.barattalo.it/2010/03/01/php-curl-bot-to-update-facebook-status/

But unfortunately non of the solution is working.So, is their any kind heart who can help me to update the facebook status using php easily?i shall be very much glud if anybody pls give any working solution. Regards---riad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've wrote a tutorial about posting to the user's wall: [How To: Post A Message On The User Wall Using Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/).

```
$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Hello from my App!',
    'link'      => 'http://www.masteringapi.com/',
    'caption'   => 'Visit MasteringAPI.com For Facebook API Tutorials!'
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);
```

Notes:

1. I'm using the [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)
2. You need the [`publish_stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission
3. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126665/need-help-on-posting-on-user-wall/5127747#5127747)

Answer (score 0):

What about checking directly the Facebook API ?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Check the "Graph API"

> The Graph API is the core of Facebook Platform, enabling you to read and write data to Facebook. It provides a simple and consistent view of the social graph, uniformly representing objects (like people, photos, events, and pages) and the connections between them (friendships, likes, and photo tags).

Comment: dear Matthieu, i already checked and generate a unexpired session key using this link http://napkin.highgroove.com/articles/2009/07/19/how-to-update-a-facebook-page-status-using-the-facebook-api but at the end here have the solution on rubi on step 3c and 4.Can u pls guide how can i submit my status?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code im my blog completely pl check that in the following link

http://scriptime.blogspot.in/2012/12/facebook-status-updates-using-php-sdk.html

here i am giving samll  code

```
  $status      = $_POST['status'];
$facebook_id = $userdata['id'];
$params      = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => $status
);
$url         = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebook_id/feed";
$ch          = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));
```