# no login page php send message to facebook friends

Tags: php, facebook, message

I want to use PHP to send message to my Facebook friends. I found some code but it just lets me log in. Could anyone help me?

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXX',
    'cookie' => true,
));

$session=$facebook->getUser();;

if ($session) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    try {
        $result = $facebook->api(
            'me/feed',
            'post',
            array('access_token' => $access_token , 'message' => 'test')
        );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you provided the correct permissions to the app?

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
               'scope' => 'publish_stream'
               ));
```

2) Check this answer: [Update facebook status using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715725/update-facebook-status-using-php) and this: [Facebook PHP SDK , Post to another users wall whats wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229498/facebook-php-sdk-post-to-another-users-wall-whats-wrong)

3) it's /me/feed, not me/feed:

```
$result = $facebook->api(
        '/me/feed',
        'post',
        array('access_token' => $access_token , 'message' => 'test')
    );
```