# How do I post on the board using the facebook curl and the graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm reading the official documentation on facebook to create the application. I found no problems, until I got to the section that explains how to publish your shouts.

How do I use this code? I do not know where to start

```
curl-F 'access_token =...' \
      -F 'message = Hello, Arjun. I like this new API. '\
      https: / / graph.facebook.com / Arjun / feed
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use facebook sdk. It's a readme file of it explaining how to connect to facebook:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/readme.md

And here is a more detailed tutorial

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
<?php

    $ogurl = "INSERT_YOUR_OG_URL_HERE";
    define(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE");
    define(FACEBOOK_SECRET, "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE");

    $mymessage = "Hello World!";

    $access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"; 
    $parameters = "type=client_cred&client_id=" . FACEBOOK_APP_ID .
        "&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_SECRET;
    $access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url . "?" . $parameters);

    $apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
    $parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" .
        urlencode($mymessage) . "&id=" . $ogurl . "&method=post";
    $myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;

    $result = file_get_contents($myurl);

    // output the post id
    echo "post_id" . $result;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to someone else asking a very similar question, here: [facebook extended permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794987/facebook-extended-permissions/5795095#5795095)

If you use the FB PHP SDK you don't need to worry about how to use cURL (though, it's pretty easy, and you can probably find some good information on the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or in the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/curl))